# How to design a database(sqlite) for multi-condition query?

Tags: sqlite, database-design

Suppose 1000,000 records arranged as:

```
c1_v1 c2_v1 c3_v1 d1
c1_v1 c2_v1 c3_v2 d2
c1_v1 c2_v1 c3_v3 d3
...
c1_v1 c2_v2 c3_v1 d999
c1_v1 c2_v2 c3_v2 d1000
...
c1_v999 c2_v999 c3_v998 d999999
c1_v999 c2_v999 c3_v999 d1000000
```

say that we need three conditions(c1_vx, c2_vx, c3_vx) to query the result(dx),  but the single condition such as c1_v1 in different records may be same. An alternative style of the records:

```
c1_v1
    c2_v1
        c3_v1 : d1
        c3_v2 : d2
        c3_v3 : d3
        ...
    c2_v2
        c3_v1 : d999
        c3_v2 : d1000
    ...
c1_v999
    c2_v999
        c3_v998: d999999
        c3_v1000: d1000000
```

How to design the tables for fasttest query? (Just query, don't care about insert/update/delete)

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify how exactly do you wish to use the conditions. Is this a simple equi-search (i.e. given values for `c1`, `c2` and `c3`, give me `d`)? Also, shouldn't you be having 999*999*999=997,002,999 rows, not 1,000,000?

Comment: Sorry, `999 is` just a subscript for SOME `c_v` rather than `1~999` for each `c_v`. `c1` is a string like `UA1000_2048X32_MCSYN`, `c2` and `c3` is a real(double) number like `1.234` or `2.3e-9`, `d` is also a real number. A typical query operation is like `select d from t_table where c1 = 'UA1000_2048X32_MCSYN' and c2 = '1.234' and c3 = '2.345';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A typical query operation is like select d from t_table where c1 = 'UA1000_2048X32_MCSYN' and c2 = '1.234' and c3 = '2.345';

Well, then you just need a composite index on `{c1, c2, c3}`.

Ideally, you'd also [cluster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the table, so retrieving `d` just involves an index seek without a table heap access, but I don't think SQLite supports clustering. Alternatively, consider creating a [covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) index on `{c1, c2, c3, d}` instead.

---

> c1 is a string like UA1000_2048X32_MCSYN, c2 and c3 is a real(double) number

I'd refrain from trying to equate numbers with strings in your query - some DBMSes can't use index in these situations and SQLite might be one of them. Instead, just write the query in most natural way, without single quotes around number literals:

```
select d from t_table
where c1 = 'UA1000_2048X32_MCSYN' and c2 = 1.234 and c3 = 2.345;
```